# vhdl reset synchronizer

Tags: fpga, vhdl, reset

I have a question regarding reset synchronizing. If I have a reset_synchronizer.vhd file like this:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity reset_synchronizer is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        reset_in : in std_logic;
        reset_out : out std_logic
    );
end entity reset_synchronizer;

architecture rtl of reset_synchronizer is

    signal dff : std_logic := '0';

begin

    process (clk, reset_in)
    begin
        if reset_in = '0' then
            reset_out <= '0';
            dff <= '0';

        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            reset_out <= dff;
            dff <= '1';

        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

and a top entity test.vhd like this:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity test is
    port (
        clk : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic
    );
end entity test;

architecture rtl of test is

    signal reset_sync : std_logic;

    component reset_synchronizer is
        port (
            clk : in std_logic;
            reset_in : in std_logic;
            reset_out : out std_logic
        );
    end component reset_synchronizer;

begin

    component_reset_synchronizer : reset_synchronizer
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset_in => reset,
            reset_out => reset_sync
        );

    async_process : process (clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '0' then
            -- Do reset

        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            -- Do something else..

        end if;
    end process async_process;

    sync_process : process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if reset = '0' then
                -- Do reset

            else
                -- Do something else..

            end if;
        end if;
    end process sync_process;
    
end architecture;
```

What would be the correct way of using the synchronous reset, async_process or sync_process?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You don't appear to have searched for previous questions on this before posting a new question. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308986/initialising-input-signals-in-vhdl/308989#308989 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416746/multiple-reset-synchronization/417999#417999

Answer (score 0):

The `sync_process` should use the `reset_sync` signal to reset, because the `reset` signal can go low and high again between two rising edges of the `clk`, and the process wouldn't notice.

Assuming you meant that, the two mechanisms are largely equivalent, the synchronous process leaves reset one cycle later though. The `reset_synchronizer` makes sure the `reset_sync` signal is asserted for at least one rising edge of `clk`, so no component that uses a synchronous reset will miss it.

The asynchronous scheme is a bit more common because most FPGA fabrics have asynchronous set/reset inputs on the registers, bypassing the lookup table, while the synchronous mechanism requires one of the lookup table inputs, effectively halving the size of the table for any element affected by the reset.