# Clock divisor for 100Hz to 25Hz: my output "out_reg" remains "don't care"

Tags: verilog

I have written code for a clock divisor for 100Hz to 25Hz but my output `out_reg` remains `don't care` when I check it in ModelSim even though `out_reg1` is correct.

```
module clock(clk, out_clk);
output reg out_clk;
reg out_clk1 = 0;
input clk ;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
     out_clk1 <= ~out_clk1; 
end
always @(posedge out_clk1)
   begin
     out_clk <= ~out_clk;   
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Use reset signal in your design.

Comment: DON'T use an initial value. Add a proper reset signal to your design, as per my answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308986/initialising-input-signals-in-vhdl/308989#308989 and also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416746/multiple-reset-synchronization/417999#417999

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no initial value for `out_clk`, and therefore the simulator doesn't know what value to assign to it when inverting an unknown value.

The following will help ModelSim determine an initial value:

```
output reg out_clk = 0;
```

In most cases, using an initial value is less preferable to using a reset signal. However in this particular case, a reset is really not necessary given that all you have is two registers toggling. The initial value is purely for the benefit of the simulation. If unavailable for synthesis, it may be necessary to wrap in a tool specific directive to mark as not for synthesis.

Comment: Exactly when i give it 0 it correctly works. but i confused that can i give initial value to registers or output registers

Comment: Do not use initial values. Use a proper reset circuit and input pin instead. The HDL is not portable. Initial values 'work' in RAM-based FPGAs but not in Flash-based FPGA, CPLDs or ASICs. Except in the specific circuit of an internal reset generator for a specific RAM-based device, initial values are to be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @TonyM Normally I'd agree to avoid initial values and add a reset, but in this particular example a reset is not required - there is no state the circuit could get into that is non-functional. The initial value here is therefore purely for simulation and has no bearing on function in hardware. To be honest though, the whole design approach needs to be abandoned - a counter and clock enable would be a much better approach.

Comment: @TonyM Feel free to write your own suggestion as an answer if you feel it is a better solution.

Comment: @TonyM Again, normally I would agree with you, but in this case unless specifically required (e.g. to stop the clock running), a reset is not required here - the initial value of both registers is completely irrelevant to expected function. The initial value is purely for simulation purposes to avoid the don't care.

Comment: *Feel free to write your own suggestion as an answer if you feel it is a better solution* Please see my previous answers, Tom and @Zerox, at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/308986/initialising-input-signals-in-vhdl/308989#308989 and also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416746/multiple-reset-synchronization/417999#417999

Comment: *initial value of...registers is...irrelevant to...function* I hear you and get your point totally: this circuit can work without a reset. So solution is: change the circuit, use reset instead, don't ever try to solve it with initial values. Actual circuit now behaves differently to simulation. Avoid that always (i.e. never do it) and it's easy to avoid here. It's paramount that the OP learns to design circuits, large or small, tiny or huge, that simulate and synthesise in agreement with each other, which leads to reliability and design job done :-) Can't post a Verilog answer,busy days @Zerox